Read multiple excel files to dataframes using for loop by reading the month in each filename
I have 12 Excel files. Each is based on a month of the year and therefore each filename ends in 'Month YYYY'. For example, the file for March of 2021 ends in 'March 2021.xlsx'. I want to read each Excel file, select certain columns, drop empty rows, then merge each file into one excel file as a named worksheet. However, I want to search the file's name, identify the month and then rename the second column to say that month.
How do I add a code to have the month of each file be used as the 'new name' for the second column of each df?
Here's an example using two months:
File one: January 2021.xlsx



A
B




1
x


3
x



File three: February 2021.xlsx



A
B




3
x


5
x



I want to rename B to represent the month of the respective excel file and then merge to get:



A
January
February




1
x
0


3
x
x


5
0
x



This is what I have done so far.
#Store Excel files in a python list
excel_files = list(Path(DATA_DIR).glob('*.xlsx'))

#Read each file into a dataframe

dfs = []

for excel_file in excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name='Sheet1',header=5,usecols='A,F',skipfooter=8)
    df.dropna(how='any', axis=0, inplace = True)
    df.rename(columns={'old-name': 'new-name'}, inplace=True)
    dfs.append(df)

#Compile the list of dataframes to merge
data_frames = [dfs[0], dfs[1],dfs[2] ... dfs[11]]

#Merge all dataframes
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['A'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames).fillna(0)

I need help adding the code to have the month of each file be used as the 'new name' for the second column of each df?

can you post an example of what you want the finished excel to look like? im a little unclear on what you want to happen

I have added some tables to give an example. It shows just 2 months but my aim is to merge all 12 months into one table.

Instead of having to go through all of that, why not have a single excel file and just use a new worksheet for the next month, that way you can do math on each month in the same document.

I think your question is similar to this:
Extract month, day and year from date regex
an advanced way to do this would be using regex, which is laid out a little in that prior post.
a simpler way to do this would be to split (or rsplit) the  on (' '), assuming that there is a space in front of the month as well as after: excel_file = "first bit of names MONTH 2021.xlsx":
for excel_file in excel_files:
    new-name = str(excel_file).rsplit(' ', 2)[-2] # creates a list [[first bit of names...], [MONTH], [2021.xlsx]] and takes the 2nd to last element
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name='Sheet1',header=5,usecols='A,F',skipfooter=8)
    df.dropna(how='any', axis=0, inplace = True)
    df.rename(columns={'old-name': new-name}, inplace=True)
    dfs.append(df)

I think this answers the question, but you may have another problem getting the "old name" in the way you propose. Hope this helps
*edited to match comment

Thank you so much! It did not work at first but I changed
new_name = excel_file.rsplit(' ', 2)[-2]  to
new_name = str(excel_file).rsplit(' ', 2)[-2] and that worked.

For the old_name, I just typed in the name of the column since they all had the same name for the second column. I put old_name in the question as a name holder.

glad I could help! regex is worth learning for other applications if you want to play around with it, it is extremely powerful.
